# Gemfire WAN Gateway-sender configuration

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

We are using the Gemfire WAN topology and have problems setting up the gateway-senders.

Couple of assumptions: 
- Replicated regions 
- Serial gateway-senders 
- manual-start is false for all gateway-senders

Let's say we have 2 clusters, within each cluster, we have 2 members (Member A and Member B)

Member A's cache.xml

```
<gfe:gateway-sender id="gateway-sender-A" parallel="false" remote-distributed-system-id="2" manual-start="false" /> 
<gfe:replicated-region name="data" scope="DISTRIBUTED_NO_ACK"> 
<gfe:replicated-region name="subData" data-policy="REPLICATE" scope="DISTRIBUTED_ACK"> 
<gfe:gateway-sender-ref bean="gateway-sender-A"/> 
</gfe:replicated-region> 
</gfe:replicated-region>
```

---

Member B's cache.xml

```
<gfe:gateway-sender id="gateway-sender-B" parallel="false" remote-distributed-system-id="2" manual-start="false" /> 
<gfe:replicated-region name="data" scope="DISTRIBUTED_NO_ACK"> 
<gfe:replicated-region name="subData" data-policy="REPLICATE" scope="DISTRIBUTED_ACK"> 
<gfe:gateway-sender-ref bean="gateway-sender-B"/> 
</gfe:replicated-region> 
</gfe:replicated-region>
```

There is a problem when we run start up the two members within one cluster. It raises this error:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create Region /data with [gateway-sender-A] gateway sender ids because another cache has the same region defined with [gateway-sender-B] gateway sender ids**

Looking at the "High Availability for Gateway Senders" documentation, our understanding is that we can create 2 gateway-senders, in which only one will be doing the sending at a given point in time. Ultimately, we want to have 2 gateway senders (one in each member) for one cache region, one as the primary sender and the other as the secondary sender.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the sender-ids to the same for both members, we have another problem:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create Gateway Sender
>   "some-gateway-sender-id" with manual start "false" because another
>   cache has the same Gateway Sender defined with manual start "true

It seems like our problem was the inconsistent format.

**Member A used [XML](http://www.gemstone.com/dtd/cache8_0.dtd) format**

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cache PUBLIC "-//GemStone Systems, Inc.//GemFire Declarative Caching 8.0//EN" "http://www.gemstone.com/dtd/cache8_0.dtd">`

**Member B used [Spring Gemfire Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/) format**

`xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd">
<gfe:gateway-sender ...>`

We switched to using the Spring Gemfire Data format for both members, and it solved both issues.

### TL;DR, the gateway-senders need to have the same ids if they are in the same cluster and use consistent cache xml formats.

Answer (score 0):

From [Geode documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/GemFire+Multi-site+(WAN)+Architecture), it says

> For serial Senders, Queue HA is achieved by configuring identical serial Senders in multiple members. The Queue is replicated between the members.

So if the two gateway senders in member A and B is doing the same job (except their primary/secondary roles), you should use "identical" setting.

Among gateway senders, there will be one that manages to acquire a specific distributed lock and becomes the primary sender, usually the first one comes up. I don't see a property to force one to become primary.

Geode is the open source version of Gemfire if you wonder.